# A problem of the plane of $2011^2$ points

Tags: geometry

Consider the set $G$ of $2011^2$ points $(x, y)$ in the plane where $x$ and $y$ are both integers between $1$ and $2011$ inclusive. Let $A$ be any subset of $G$ containing at least $4×2011×\sqrt{2011}$ points. Show that there are at least $2011^2$ parallelograms whose vertices lie in $A$ and all of whose diagonals meet at a single point.

I assume $S$ to be the set of all segments whose endpoints lie in $A$, so $|S| =$ $ m(m−1)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The middle of two points in $A$ is one of $\sim 4N^2$ grid points with integer or half-integer coordinates between $1$ and $N$. From the $4N\sqrt N$ points in $A$, we can form $\sim 8 N^3$ such pairs, hence find a mid point that is common to $\sim 2N$ pairs. Two such pairs give rise to a parallelogram unless the pairs are collinear (and the parallelogram degenerates). Note that for a given midpoint and line, there are at most $\sim\frac N2$ point pairs on that line with that midpoint. Thus each of the $\sim 2N$ point pairs makes a parallelogram with at least $\sim \frac 32N$ point pairs. In total, that gives us (noting that each parallelogram is counted twice) at least $$\sim \frac32N^2$$ parallelograms.
The desired result is $N^2$, so there is much leewy available when we make all the "$\sim$" estimates rigorous. (For each claim $A\sim B$ above, it is straightforward to show $B(1-\frac kN)< A<B(1+\frac kN)$ for some very small $k\ll \sqrt N$, say)